# Add custom margin to pdf page with a certain element in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, pdf, puppeteer

I need to convert my web page into a pdf, In the web page there are existing image which will occupy an entire pdf page of size a4. So I need that exact page with the image  to have margin as 0px.We are using puppeteer in headless mode

we tried using css

```
@page{
    margin: 50px;
}

@page margin0 {
    margin:0px;
}

.margin-zero-image {
    page: margin0;
}
```

did not work as named pages support seems to be removed in puppeteer

we tried looping through the all the pdf pages using buffer and merging the buffer but the pdf gets corrupted while trying this